# SQL Linked Server Login Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to create a Linked Server to another SQL server by using a windows user login that has been granted 'dbreader' permissions on the target server for specific database but I am getting the error message 'Login Failed'.

I can login onto the source SQL server using the windows user login and with SQL SMS I can access to target server and view tables and data without any issues.

Any ideas greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the Windows login, but with the Servers. The error actually means that Server A doesn't have the permission to login to Server B.

The same issue has been discussed here : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-am-i-getting-a-login-failed-when-creating-this-linked-server

Comment: Thanks for that.. I will check with 3rd Party IT about Kerberos acceptance to the target sever as this user is a service account.

Comment: @fgt: You can check whether you're able to connect to each server individually using Kerberos by doing `select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@SPID;`. You need only check it for the source server in your case, but I like having it configured for all servers as it clears up that headache for all potential combinations in the future.

Comment: Thanks Ben.. I checked the source server and Kerberos was returned.. Getting IT to check target...